how do I check all the numbers in a string in one action?
I want to check that no digit in the number occurs more than 4 times. How can I shorten this line into one or two actions?
s.count('1') < 5 and s.count('2') < 5 and s.count('3') < 5 and s.count('4') < 5 and s.count('5') < 5 and s.count('6') < 5 and s.count('7') < 5 and s.count('8') < 5:

I was thinking of doing some sort of iteration of each number and comparing it with 5. Maybe through range

Something like
from collections import Counter

all(x <= 4 for x in Counter(s).values())

Each call to s.count has to traverse the entire string, whereas Counter(s) needs to traverse the string only once.

Strings don't mind being traversed multiple times, that's no problem.

@nocomment Strings don't mind, but the human being waiting for the inefficient program to complete will (if the string is long enough).

@nocomment Sorry, I didn't see your answer.

@AKX Let me try a longer string as well...

@AKX For my test string string multiplied by 1000, my solution is over 20 times faster than this. I was already doing this solution a favor by testing only a short string.

max(map(s.count, '12345678')) < 5

map applies s.count to every one of those digits, yielding the counts. Then just check that the largest count is under 5.
A little benchmark:
s = '1222322455555678009000'
  2.1 ± 0.2 μs  max(map(s.count, '12345678')) < 5
  3.4 ± 0.2 μs  Counter(s)
  4.9 ± 0.5 μs  all(x <= 4 for x in Counter(s).values())

Python: 3.12.0 (main, Oct  7 2023, 10:42:35) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]

And with a longer string:
s = '1222322455555678009000' * 1000
  98.5 ±  12.1 μs  max(map(s.count, '12345678')) < 5
2186.5 ± 201.4 μs  Counter(s)
2428.2 ± 173.8 μs  all(x <= 4 for x in Counter(s).values())

Script (Attempt This Online!):
from timeit import repeat

setup = '''
from collections import Counter
s = '1222322455555678009000'
'''

funcs = [
    "max(map(s.count, '12345678')) < 5",
    'all(x <= 4 for x in Counter(s).values())',
    'Counter(s)',
]

from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
import sys
import random

exec(setup)
print(f'{s = !r}')

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e6 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} μs '
for _ in range(25):
    random.shuffle(funcs)
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(f, setup, number=10**4) / 10**4
        times[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)


Nice benchmark and catch with poor Counter's performance. You could also add my solution to the benchmark, which performs similarly to yours.

@hnwoh The problem is that it depends on the digits. For s='1111', mine is faster and for s='11111', yours is faster. And for long strings, yours can be up to ten times faster. I didn't want to make a decision about that and didn't want to mislead. And really my only goal was to show how slow Counter is, especially since chepner made it sound like it's fast. That always bothers me.

@hnwoh Though I just checked the question again, they said "digit in the number", so I guess the whole string is just digits, in which case my * 1000 string benchmark doesn't make much sense - if they had such long strings and wanted it fast, they might want to check len(s) <= 40 first, and not count at all if that's not the case.

You can try using all() which returns True only if all elements in iterable are True:
s = '123455556789'
result = all(s.count(digit) < 5 for digit in '1234567890')


There are already some clever one-line answers, but I wanted to write a long one that you may find easier to follow.
number = '1222322455555678009000'

success = True
for digit in number:            # Loop through the digits in the number
    if number.count(digit) > 4: # Check if each one appears more than 4 times
        print(f'{digit} found > 4 times')
        success = False         # As soon as one does, record this fact
        break                   # And exit the loop

if success:
    print('The number is OK')
else:
    print('The number failed the test')

Output:
2 found > 4 times
The number failed the test


You can do as you said.
Or you might use comprehensions:
max([s.count(chr(c)) for c in range(ord('1'),ord('8')+1)]) < 5
Here we build a list made of only occurences of numeric characters in s.
Ord gives the integer value of characters. chr converts that value back to a character, since s.count requires c to be a character.
Then we verify that the maximum value in that list is less than 5.
I hope it's clear.
However, doing a loop may be easier to understand I think.
